# Oracle SQL - Determine if a timestamp falls within a range, excluding date

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

I'm looking for a way to determine if a timestamp falls between two times, regardless of the *date* in that timestamp.  So for example, if the time in the timestamp falls between '00:00:00.000' (midnight) and '01:00:00.000' (1 A.M.), I'd want to select that row regardless of the particular date.

I've tried lots of different variations on the `to_char` and `to_date` functions, but I keep getting errors.  Coming from Informix, Oracle seems much more complicated.

The thing closest to "correct" (I think) that I've tried is:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(my_timestamp), 10) > '00:00:00.000'
AND SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(my_timestamp), 10) < '01:00:00.000'
```

... But nothing works.  Any tips or tricks?

I found a way to do it, but I'd still prefer something a little less hacky, if it exists.

```
SUBSTR(SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(my_timestamp), 11), 0, 12) > '01.00.00.000'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution looks correct to me except I haven't tried substr function. This is what I used in one of my previous project:

```
select * from orders 
   where to_char(my_timestamp,'hh24:mi:ss.FF3') 
   between '00:00:00.000' and '01:00:00.123';
```

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that `between` is inclusive. It might be safer to use `>=` and `<` to avoid overlapping periods, at the cost of doing the conversion to a string twice.

Answer (score 1):

Use `TRUNC(my_timestamp, 'J')` to remove the hours and get only the '2013-08-15 00:00:00.00'.
So:

```
WHERE my_timestamp - TRUNC(my_timestamp, 'J') > 0 
AND my_timestamp - TRUNC(my_timestamp, 'J') < 1/24 ;
```

Comment: I don't get it.  I'm not trying to remove the hours -- I want to remove the date.  Maybe I'm missing what you're saying?

Comment: @JeffGohlke - the point is that the difference between a date and the `trunc` of that date is the number of hours, as a fraction of a day. So at midday, `sysdate - trunc(sysdate)` would be 0.5. You can use that value to figure out the timeslot. However, for timestamp (rather than date) I think that gives you an interval, not a number, so I'm not sure if this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

As a variation on @kubanczyk's answer, since these are timestamps you get an interval when you subtract a value from its truncated form:

```
select systimestamp - trunc(systimestamp) from dual;

SYSTIMESTAMP-TRUNC(SYSTIMESTAMP)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
+000000000 09:46:46.589795
```

Which isn't very helpful. But if you're always looking for exact hours, as in your example, you can extract the hour number from that:

```
select extract (hour from systimestamp - trunc(systimestamp)) from dual;

EXTRACT(HOURFROMSYSTIMESTAMP-TRUNC(SYSTIMESTAMP))
-------------------------------------------------
                                                9
```

So in your example you could use:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE EXTRACT(HOUR FROM my_timestamp - TRUNC(my_timestamp)) = 0
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c5e79/1).

But, this will only be straightforward if the timeslots are exactly aligned with hours; otherwise you'd need to extract other elements too and the logic could get confusing, and @Ankit's approach will be simpler overall.